# How to override a xml file and phtml in magento 2?

Tags: layout

How to Do? this i was trying to override the default.xml.can anyone tell how to do this.
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override deafult.xml file by creating you own custom theme. if you are not aware of custom theme in magento then you can refer magento theme docs.
hope this helps.